# How to get parameters from strings in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, parameters, arguments

How can I get some parameters from a string in Python.

Let's say the string contains two words which I want to use as parameters. These are of course separated by spaces.
Example:

```py
string = "Lorem Ipsum"

def funct(hereLorem, hereIpsum)
```

Comment: Do you want to declare a function using the arguments in that string, or call a function using those strings as parameters?

Comment: I want to call a function with these parameters as arguments.

Comment: I've added an answer which I think answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a string.split(optional delimiter). This returns a list.

Example:

```
l = string.split()
```

and if you're expecting a certain pattern

```
arg1 = l[0]
arg2 = l[1]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function to take a variable number of arguments, and then use split to get these arguments from the string.

```
# Define a function that can take variable number of arguments
def some_func(*args):
    print(args)

# Split string on spaces to get args
s = "Lorem Ipsum"
args = s.split(' ')

# Call function with arguments
some_func(*args)
```

Ouput:

```
('Lorem', 'Ipsum')
```